# iOS Block image return

Tags: ios, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

So I am working on a project and I *must* use `AFImageDownloader` in order to download some images that we need to use in our project. I use the following code:

```
-(void) downloadImage:(NSURL*) url
{
    AFHTTPSessionManager *sessionManager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];
    AFImageDownloader    *imgDownloader = [[AFImageDownloader alloc] initWithSessionManager:sessionManager downloadPrioritization:AFImageDownloadPrioritizationFIFO maximumActiveDownloads:1 imageCache:nil];    
    AFHTTPResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json",@"binary/octet-stream",nil];
    sessionManager.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [imgDownloader downloadImageForURLRequest:req success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *responseObject){
        self.image = responseObject;
        [self.delegate updateImageWithImage:self.image]; // ** CRASH **

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }];
}
```

The delegate is of course not *nil* and code of the updateImageWithImage is:

```
-(void) updateImageWithImage:(UIImage*) img {
   self.image.image = img;
}
```

So basically when I try to get the `UIImage` I get it as a response and assign it to the `UICollectionViewCell` and it crashes! I guess that I should do some kind of "copy" of the `responseObject` before using it in order parts of my program, but I am not really sure what the problem is. Any ideas?

Comment: What does the debugger say after crash?

Comment: after `self.image = responseObject;` check once the value of `self.image` by printing it.

Comment: I am using xcode 8 BTW, and the debugger says: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: You are using threading without knowing what you're doing. You need to get onto the main thread! And do _not_ use a `self.image` property; this can change out from under you if you get called simultaneously on multiple threads. Never touch the interface when your data is downloaded; modify the _model_ (the place where your data is stored) and then tell the collection view to reload (on the main thread).

Comment: @triple.s I checked the value and seems Ok, a perfectly fine UIImage

Comment: There will be more text to the exception than just that. There should be a reason that the exception was thrown; eg unrecognised selector etc

Comment: @Paulw11 that would be true in xcode < 8, but xcode 8 debugger sucks. And I am stuck with Xcode 8 because of the project specs! I *must* use it!

Comment: Is any of your code in Swift?  If not then you can just load it under Xcode 7.3 just to test. Xcode 8 is beta and I wouldn't use it for anything important yet. I would suggest that you code your delegate invocation more defensively and use `respondsToSelector` before you invoke the delegate method and as Matt says there is no reason to pass a property to your delegate method; pass a local variable

Comment: Have you set an exception breakpoint?

Comment: You are right @Paulw11but I am writting and iMessage extension which only exists on xcode 8, the project doesn't seem to even compile on xcode 7.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117854/discussion-between-paulw11-and-ignacio-orona).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was basically using AFImagedownloader wrong, this is the proper way to use this Class:

```
[self.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:jpegURLRequest

                      placeholderImage:placeholder

                                   success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, UIImage *image){

                                       NSLog(@"Success");



                                       completionBlock(image);

                                   }

                               failure:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

                                   NSLog(@"ERROR!!!");

                               }];
```